# React Date Picker Highlight not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am having an issue where the dates I have indicated to be highlighted in React Date Picker are not highlighting.

Update: I fixed the issue and I am hoping It helps someone.

```
  const handleDayClick = (value) => {
    var tempselectedBlackOutDays = selectedBlackOutDays;
    const selectedIndex = tempselectedBlackOutDays.findIndex((selectedDay) =>
      isEqual(selectedDay, value)
    );

    if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
      tempselectedBlackOutDays.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    } else {
      tempselectedBlackOutDays.push(value);
    }

    setSelectedBlackOutDays(tempselectedBlackOutDays);
  };
```

Here is the fix to the above. I changed the last line to

```
setSelectedBlackOutDays(tempselectedBlackOutDays.map((x) => x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix to the above. I changed the last line to

```
setSelectedBlackOutDays(tempselectedBlackOutDays.map((x) => x))
```

It appears I needed to use map. I thought those arrays were thesame. Hopefully some expert can chime in.